# What's the meaning of this effect?

Tags: analysis, effects, the-departed

In *The Departed* (2006), before meeting Dignam and Queenan in the Special Investigation Unit building, Sullivan is
framed in a small circle as he stands near a traffic signal, which enlarges to full screen:

[image]

What's the meaning of this effect?

Comment: If they didn't zoom out from him, you wouldn't know what you're supposed to be looking at. Are you supposed to be looking at the car? The lamppost? The smoking bystander?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> An [iris shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_shot) is a technique used [...] to emphasize a detail of a scene above all others, more commonly to end or open a scene. Iris shots are also used to put emphasis on a particular aspect of film, usually something of importance.

This isn't a technique that's used a lot nowadays as it's more of an old-fashion way to emphasize. It can also be a tribute to the "old days" too.

Comment: Holy attention grabber, Batman! Pow! Bammm!